# PHPで日付のバリデーションを行いたいです

Tags: php

タイトルの通りです。
行いたいバリデーションの内容は以下の３つです。

ユーザーが入力した日付が
・5,10,15,20,25日である
・月末である
・過去30日以内である（１ヶ月に変更になる可能性有）

自分なりに書いてみたコードはこんな感じです。
※$check['Date']には YYYY/mm/dd の形式でDBから取ってきたデータが入っています。

```
//30日以内
function DateChk30( $check ) {
    $today = date("Y/m/d");
    $checkunix = strtotime($check['Date']);
    $todatunix = strtotime($today);
    $diff = ($todatunix - $checkunix ) / ( 60 * 60 * 24);

    if ($diff < 30 ) 
    { 
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}

//5,10,15,20,25,月末
function DateChk( $check ) {
    $wk = date('Y/m/t');               //月末
    $tmp = substr($check['Date'], -2); //後ろ２文字
    $tmp = (int)$tmp;

    if ( ($tmp % 5) == 0 || $check['Date'] == $wk) 
    {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

これだと31日が存在する月の30日でも通してしまうので困っています。
switchを使って1日ずつ設定するしかないでしょうか。。
何か良い方法がありましたらご教授ください。
また、全体的に拙いソースだと思いますので、綺麗に書ける書き方があればご教授ください。

よろしくお願いします。

Comment: マルチポスト　https://teratail.com/questions/87716

Answer (score 1):

挙動確認してませんが、例えば以下のようにしてみてはどうでしょうか。

・5,10,15,20,25日である

```php
function isMultipleOf5($date) {
    $day = date('d', strtotime($date));
    return (($day % 5) == 0 && $day < 30) ? true : false;
}
```

・月末である

```php
function getEndOfMonth($date) {
    $yearmonth = date('y/m', strtotime($date));
    return date('Y/m/d', strtotime("last day of {$yearmonth}"));
}

function isEndOfMonth($date) {
    $endOfMonth = getEndOfMonth($date);
    return ($date === $endOfMonth) ? true : false;
}
```

[PHP: 相対的な書式 - Manual](http://php.net/manual/ja/datetime.formats.relative.php)

・過去30日以内である（１ヶ月に変更になる可能性有）

```php
function within30Days($date) {
    $diff = strtotime("-30 days") - strtotime("{$date} -30 days");
//    $diff = strtotime("-1 month") - strtotime("{$date} -1 month");
    return ($diff < 0) ? true : false;
}
```

Answer (score 1):

こちらの条件を満たせる形で記述いたします。

> 5,10,15,20,25日である

モジュラ演算子を利用せずとも下記で対応可能です。
また、特別な日付のみを追加する(1日など)などといったイレギュラーパターンにも対応可能です。
こちらのほうが見栄えもよく、あとに利用する方がどういった処理をしているのか、わかりやすいかと思います。(PHPの性質を使い、あえてstrictパラメータは付与しません。)

```
<?php
if (in_array(date('d', strtotime($check['Date'])), [5, 10, 15, 20, 25])) {
     // do something
}
```

> 月末である

月末の判定は`date('t')`で判定できます。こちらもあえて、曖昧な比較にしています。

```
<?php
if (date('t') == date('d', strtotime($check['Date']))) {
     // do something
}
```

> 過去30日以内である（１ヶ月に変更になる可能性有）

過去30日以内であるということは現在の日付 - 30日なので、下記のようになります。
変わる場合があるとのことなので、`-30 days`の箇所は月であれば`-1 month`に変えてください。

```
<?php
if (strtotime('-30 days', strtotime($check['Date'])) <= time()) {
    // do something
}
```

これらを組み合わせて下記となります。

```
<?php
if (
    in_array(date('d', strtotime($check['Date'])), [5, 10, 15, 20, 25]) &&
    date('t') == date('d', strtotime($check['Date'])) &&
    strtotime('-30 days', strtotime($check['Date'])) <= time()
) {
     // 条件に一致した場合の処理
}
```

上記で解説している方法は、PHPの曖昧な比較を利用した手法です。
詳しく知りたい場合は下記をご覧ください。
http://php.net/manual/ja/function.in-array.php
http://php.net/manual/ja/types.comparisons.php

蛇足: 本来はイミュータブルなDateTimeを使うのが望ましいでしょうが、今回はstrtotimeで割愛します。

**2017/08/24 追記**

失礼しました。
過去30日以内判定のロジックに誤りがありました。正確には下記のようになります。

```
<?php
if (strtotime($check['Date']) >= strtotime('-30 days')) {
    // do something
}
```

Answer (score 0):

多少冗長ですが、既存の関数をあまり変えないで見やすさ重視の場合は

```
//5,10,15,20,25,月末
function DateChk( $check ) {
    $wk = date('Y/m/t');               //月末
    $tmp = substr($check['Date'], -2); //後ろ２文字
    $tmp = (int)$tmp;

    if ( $tmp == 5 || $tmp == 10 || $tmp == 15 || $tmp == 20 || $tmp == 25 || $check['Date'] == $wk) 
    {
        return true;
    } else {
        return false;
    }
}
```

ワンライナーでソース量の少ないかつ意味もわかるような修正だと探したい日付をarrayで保持してのほうがいいかな。

```
function DateChk( $check ) {
    if ($check['Date'] == date('Y/m/t') || in_array((int)substr($check['Date'], -2), array(5,10,15,20,25)))
    {
       return true;
    }
    return false;

}
```

Answer (score 0):

mktime()を使うと、月、年、閏月を跨いでの処理が簡単になると思います。
日付だけプラマイすればタイムスタンプを計算してくれます。

```
//30日まえ
$d30 = mktime(0, 0, 0, date("m")  , date("d")-30, date("Y"));
echo date("Y/m/d H:i:s",$d30);
```

同様に、月だけプラマイすれば、1ヶ月前、後も

```
$d30 = mktime(0, 0, 0, date("m")-1  , date("d"), date("Y"));
```

また、日付だけに変換とか使うとより楽しく作業出来るでしょう。

```
echo date("d",time());
```